# Appropriate use of PHP session in CMS?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I was hoping to get your input on a CMS that I am creating.  How it is currently setup, on a visitors first page load the system queries the "site" table and pulls down any site wide data (ie. Site ID/Site name/Site wide hooks etc.).  This information is stored in PHP session and that table does not get queried again for the remainder of the users visit.

Does this sound acceptable?  I like the idea of saving an unnecessary db query on every page load however, if the site has a large amount of hooks, this session var could get large (unlikely but possible).

For extra information, the system currently runs a config class that could store some site data (thus preventing even the first db query) however I want the plugin system to easily be able integrate hooks into this CMS so I decided a DB route was the way to go.

I would appreciate your input. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need in overcomplicating things, K.I.S.S will serve you good here. Start optimizing when you actually need it. You should also remember that the database will most likely cache the query and the result if it's done multiple times so there's no guarantee that you will save any time at all.